# Android studio app randomly runs out of memory

Tags: java, android

I am building a small app which yesterday worked just fine, but today after adding a button did not. I reverted all my changes but I still get the same error, that the app runs out of memory. This is the code and stack trace:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}}
```

Logcat: http://pastebin.com/UdAFp32h

I did find something interesting in the Logcat:

```
03-29 14:34:42.067 20964-20964/com.example.antongustafsson.csnappen
A/art:art/runtime/runtime.cc:291]   at
com.example.antongustafsson.csnappen.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:15)

03-29 14:34:42.067 20964-20964/com.example.antongustafsson.csnappen
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:291]   at
com.example.antongustafsson.csnappen.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:16)

03-29 14:34:42.067 20964-20964/com.example.antongustafsson.csnappen
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:291]   at
com.example.antongustafsson.csnappen.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:16)

03-29 14:34:42.067 20964-20964/com.example.antongustafsson.csnappen
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:291]   at
com.example.antongustafsson.csnappen.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:16)

03-29 14:34:42.067 20964-20964/com.example.antongustafsson.csnappen
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:291]   ... **repeated 261584 times**
```

It looks like I got a infinite loop going, except I do not. Does anyone know anything I could try? Why does this error just randomly occur?

Comment: Why are you creating a `MainActivity` inside the MainActivity?

Comment: If you need an instance of your `MainActivity` class, just use the `this` keyword.

Comment: yes, I just realized this. Damn, I think I'm tired! Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your class `MainActivity` repeaditly creates new instances of `MainActivity`, since the variable declaration and initalization

```
MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
```

will lead to an endless recursion that does create instances of `MainActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

For your future issues with memory:
Try to use **Eclipse Memory Analyzer Tool** to profile your memory and track potential memory leaks

http://www.eclipse.org/mat/